# Scroll lag when many photos

Tags: jquery, css, image, browser

Consider these two cases:
[High-defs](http://jsfiddle.net/cLmufw5u/2/) vs [Low-defs](http://jsfiddle.net/9v6bebqg/)

When scrolling through the pics, there is noticeable lag on the high-def ones vs low-def.
If, resizing the actual photos isn't an option,  then what can I do to make the scrolling smoother for the high-def list?

Comment: it lag b/c your image is still loading, if you can find out all the image size before hand, and load the layout first, before you load the image, it will reduce it.

Comment: It lags after the images are fully loaded. it has nothing to do with loading. it's the sheer size.

Comment: haha, it didn't lag on my after it's cached. sorry can't help you there... but do you really want to dump close to 40mb of photo on people?

Comment: @wlin I am exploring my options, and this is just an example...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to load all images on the same time when the page is loaded. Page load time it's a bottleneck on user's rejection. To create a great user experience, I recommend [LazyLoad plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). It restricts image loading only to viewport, loading the other ones when users scrolls down the page. It's awesome.

Another good practice is to delimit width and height so the browser doesn't need to [repaint and reflow](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/).

If you don't like those tips you can implement a javascript queue for loading images. :

```
images = [];

for (var i in t){ 
    images.push(t[i].image_url);
}

function loadNextImg() {
    if (!images.length) return false;

    var img = new Image();
    img.alt = "your-alt";
    img.width = 150;
    img.onload = loadNextImg;

    img.src = images.splice(0,1);
    document.body.appendChild(img)
}
loadNextImg();
```

Unfortunately this method doesn't take advantage of paralell download, but makes the process smoother. With little modifications you can download more than one image at the same time. You can find this code working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ubgeLq2s/